# How do I convert this docker command to docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run this command manually:

```
$ docker run -it --rm \
    --network app-tier \
    bitnami/cassandra:latest cqlsh --username cassandra --password cassandra cassandra-server
```

But I don't know how to convert it to a docker compose file, specially the container's custom properties such as `--username` and `--password`.

What should I write in a docker-compose.yaml file to obtain the same result?

Thanks

Comment: I see a lot of commandline arguments after the image which are mostly not part of the configuration of the docker image but part of the commandline to start the application within the image. So these are mostly not configured in the docker-compose file

Comment: Online : https://8gwifi.org/dc1.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of how others have done it. http://abiasforaction.net/apache-cassandra-cluster-docker/

Running the command below

```
command:
```

Setting arg's below

```
environment:
```

Remember just because you can doesn't mean you should.. Compose is not always the best way to launch something. Often it can be the lazy way.

If your running this as a service id suggest building the dockerfile to start and then creating systemd/init scripts to rm/relaunch it.

Answer (score 2):

an example cassandra docker-compose.yml might be

```
version: '2'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: 'bitnami/cassandra:latest'
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9160:9160'
    volumes:
      - 'cassandra_data:/bitnami'
volumes:
  cassandra_data:
    driver: local
```

although this will not provide you with your commandline arguments but start it with the default CMD or ENTRYPOINT.

As you are actually running another command then the default you might not want to do this with docker-compose. Or you can create a new Docker image with this command as the default and provide the username and password as ENV's

e.g. something like this (untested)

```
FROM bitnami/cassandra:latest

ENV USER=cassandra
ENV PASSWORD=password

CMD ["cqlsh", "--username", "$USER", "--password", "$PASSWORD", "cassandra-server"]
```

and you can build it

```
docker build -t mycassandra .
```

and run it with something like:

```
docker run -it -e "USER=foo" -e "PASSWORD=bar" mycassandra
```

or in docker-compose

```
services:
  cassandra:
    image: 'mycassandra'
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '9042:9042'
      - '9160:9160'
    environment:
      USER:user
      PASSWORD:pass
    volumes:
      - 'cassandra_data:/bitnami'
volumes:
  cassandra_data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1):

You might looking for something like the following. Not sure if it is going to help you....

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      my_app:
        image: bitnami/cassandra:latest
        command: /bin/sh -c cqlsh --username cassandra --password cassandra cassandra-server
        ports:
         - "8080:8080"
        networks:
         - app-tier
    networks:
     app-tier:
      external: true
```